# Game display isn't centered

Tags: 13.10, wine, games

Whenever I play a game using Wine the game is off centered or zoomed into the top left corner of the game.How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because game resolution is smaller than your system screen resolution. Wine can not change resolution, and that is good. Your options include:

- Find a way to increase game resolution to your actual resolution.
- Decrese system screen resolution when playing.
- Wine has an option to redirect fullscreen back to windows in it's `winecfg` settings. Use it, than use Ubuntu accessibility tools to scale that window to fullscreen.

Comment: I found a solution by going into winecfg . Go into the graphics tabs and make sure "emulate a virtual desktop" is checked and then set the resolution to the desired setting